# Проверка куки

Tags: сессия, cookie, php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы при входе на страницу проверялось авторизован ли человек или нет, если да то его перекидывает на страницу, а если нет, то его перекидывает на страницу авторизации.
Гуглил, но ни чего не нашел :(

Comment: Гугль оффлайн?  
Введите **авторизация php**

Comment: Rein, он же гуглил... ))

Comment: вот именно

Comment: А у меня вполне годные статьи нашлись по этому запросу.

Answer (score 1):

очень просто! в случае авторизации сохраняем в сессию ID пользователя. соответственно если его нет - пользователь неавторизован и бросаем его на страницу авторизации.

если по шагам:

1 [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php) - открывает&продолжает сессию по переданному в куках [PHPSESSID](http://php.net/session.name) или через GET или POST-переменную. Сессия, как и ассоциативный массив, позволяет хранить пары ключ = значение. Обьекты классов, насколько мне известно, хранить нельзя, но можно их сериализовать и сохранить. Доступ к данным сессии можно получить через суперглобальную переменную [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.session.php)

2 проверяем залогинен ли пользователь:

> `if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_id']) && /*можно разных проверок написать*/){
> // пользователь авторизован. его $id = $_SESSION['user_id']
> }else{
> // пользователь неавторизован. перенаправление на страницу логина
> return; // или аналог
> }`

3 Всё! у вас есть id пользователя. все остальное можно взять из бд. Можно также в сессию писать время последнего входа и сверять что, например, через 30 минут неактивности бросать на страницу авторизации (автовыход). хотя я не уверен что именно это так делается *(есть lifetime у куков, может они тут привязаны)*

4 выход (logout)

> `unset($_SESSION['user_id'])`

PS сессии хранятся на сервере, вообще их можно хранить как в файлах (стандартный способ), так и в бд.

PPS вообще рекомендую использовать фреймворки. они отчасти хороши тем, что некоторые тонкие моменты там учтены, что-то упрощено и порой не нужно задумыватся над тем, что там внутри происходит. хотя бывает и наоборот).

В официальной документации всё описано.
[Функции для работы с сессиями](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.session.php)

Comment: Помню раньше смотрел офф. документацию по session_start() - там было все-все подробно описано, в каких случаях сессия открывается, в каких продолжается. Помоему по IP даже открывалась, без куков. Сейчас меньше, или это мне просто кажется?

Comment: а как сделать кнопку выход? какую сессию надо написать?

Comment: пункт 4. дописал

Comment: ок всё вижу, но я нашел статейку лучше http://pyha.ru/articles/php/auth/

Comment: чего вопрос тогда задавать. тема простейшая

Comment: согласен, уже усвоил)